# unable to return view from a controller through ModelAndView instance?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**Situation :** I am trying out a spring webapp. The name of app is `spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload`

My web.xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>            
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-   
class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And rest-servlet.xml is as follows :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.hmkcode.spring.mvc.controllers" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean id="multipartResolver"  
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Now when application is run , `index.html`  is displayed successfully . it has a following anchor tag :

```
<a href="rest/controller/next">Next</a>
```

The method `Next()` that handles this request and returns a form.jsp is as follows :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/controller")
public class FileController {
@RequestMapping(value="/next", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Next() {

    return new ModelAndView("C:\\Users\\Varrox\\Desktop\\"
            + "spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload\\src\\main\\"
            + "webapp\\form.jsp","wl-entity",new Sample());
}
}
```

**Problem :** The problem i am facing is that when i click on `next` link located in `index.html` i am getting an error saying "**No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload/rest/controller/C:/Users/Varrox/Desktop/spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload/src/main/webapp/form.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'**".

as you can see when `Next()` method in controller returns `ModelAndView` instance along with the viewname the app prefixes `spring-mvc-jquery-file-upload/rest/controller` before the viewname and that is why no mapping is found.

How do i remove this prefix so that mapping can occur correctly and my form.jsp is displayed .

Comment: [spring] guys, why is there still no canonical duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22No+mapping+found+for+HTTP+request+with+URI%22+%22in+DispatcherServlet+with+name%22 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect a Java app to be able to load a ressource that is not in the classpath. This will not work.

You need a viewResolver, that will be used to find a view by its name.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this exemple, note the prefix that handle the root path, and suffix the file extension

Then you simple use the file name :

```
 return new ModelAndView("form","wl-entity",new Sample());
```

Full exemple here [Spring MVC file upload example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/)